# Code to not allow users with greater versions of 07 MS Access

Tags: ms-access, module, vba

I have a program I don't want to split but I want to allow some users to use but basically im the only one that uses it. The problem is there are a few users that 2016 and if they open it then I have broken references ect and I just don't want to go through the splitting and distributing of something that is looked at maybe once and here in a year im going to 2016 anyway.

My question is, is there a way I can on my first form that opens check what version they are running and if its greater than 2007 give them a message and close the database? If so how and please give me an example code... Thanks!

```
If CurrentProject.FileFormat <= 12 Then
'""
End If

If CurrentProject.FileFormat > 12 Then
MsgBox Application.Name & ", Version " & "is to high to be ran with this    database try a 2007 version"
Exit Sub
```

End If

Comment: mdialogo, wouldn't what I added to my initial post work from your example? Also, I cant get it to exit sub

Comment: I couldn't figure out why my DB want closing I was using exit sub instead of Quit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Application.Version`, which returns the Access application version.

```
If CInt(Application.Version) > 12
    MsgBox Application.Name & ", Version " & Application.Version & "is to high to be ran with this    database try a 2007 version"
    Application.Quit
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [CurrentProject.FileFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb240501(v=office.12).aspx) property.  Hope it helps.

```
Dim strFormat As String 

Select Case CurrentProject.FileFormat 
 Case acFileFormatAccess2 
 strFormat = "Microsoft Access 2" 
 Case acFileFormatAccess95 
 strFormat = "Microsoft Access 95" 
 Case acFileFormatAccess97 
 strFormat = "Microsoft Access 97" 
 Case acFileFormatAccess2000 
 strFormat = "Microsoft Access 2000" 
 Case acFileFormatAccess2002 
 strFormat = "Access 2002 - 2003" 
 Case acFileFormatAccess12 
 strFormat = "Microsoft Access 2007" 
End Select 

MsgBox "This is a " &; strFormat &; " project."
```

Comment: That doesn't work. Opening it in Access 2016 will return "Microsoft Access 2007", it refers to the database file format, not the application version.